# qmake subproject in CMake project

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cmake, qmake

I've got a CMake based project with the following "design":

```
add_subdirectory(first_lib)
add_subdirectory(second_lib)
add_subdirectory(qt_application)
```

My question is - can I create a qt_application subproject as a qmake based? I think it will be much easier.

It it is impossible - how can I manage it in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake is perfectly capable of building a Qt project. All of KDE uses CMake.

See [Qt's documentation](http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects).

Comment: I will check it. I know, that KDE is using CMake, but I have no idea how CMake handles *.ui files.